# How to write in pdo method

Tags: php, pdo

How to rewrite this in pdo:

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost:".$LOCAL_DB_PORT, $LOCAL_DB_USER, $LOCAL_DB_PASS);
 mysql_select_db("xnews", $con);
 mysql_query("set names utf8", $con);
```

Comment: Check out http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=xnews;host=localhost;port=' . $LOCAL_DB_PORT, $LOCAL_DB_USER, $LOCAL_DB_PASS);
$db->query('set names utf8');
```

To open a connection, you have to instanciate PDO, using its [constructor](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), which receives a DSN as first parameter.

And, then, to send queries, you can use the [`PDO::query`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method.

Or, for the UTF-8 part, maybe you could use the fourth parameter to [`PDO::__construct`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php), like this :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=xnews;host=localhost;port=' . $LOCAL_DB_PORT, 
          $LOCAL_DB_USER, 
          $LOCAL_DB_PASS, 
          array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  "SET NAMES 'UTF8'")
      );
```

See the list of specific stuff for the [MySQL Driver](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), amongst which there is this one :

> `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`
>
> Command to execute when connecting to
>   the MySQL server. Will automatically
>   be re-executed when reconnecting.